# How do I navigate from one view to another in Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, caliburn.micro

So let me put it this way.

I have a `LogInViewModel` and a `LogInView`. There is a `Login()` method in the ViewModel that gets called if the user clicks on a button in the View. Now I want the dashboard to show if the login was successful. How do I do this? I can't find a clear answer to this in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your dashboard is essentially your shell.  In which case, you can bootstrap your `LoginViewModel` and in the `Login` method, after a successful login, you can show the `DashboardViewModel` and close the `LoginViewModel` using the Caliburn.Micro `WindowManager`.

Something like (using MEF):

Bootstrapper.cs

```
public class Bootstrapper : Caliburn.Micro.Bootstrapper<ILoginViewModel>
{
  ...
}
```

LoginViewModel.cs

```
public class LoginViewModel : Screen, ILoginViewModel
{
    private readonly IWindowManager windowManager;

    private readonly IDashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public LoginViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager, IDashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel)
    {
        this.windowManager = windowManager;
        this.dashboardViewModel = dashboardViewModel;
    }

    public void Login()
    {            
        // if login success...
        this.windowManager.ShowDialog(this.dashboardViewModel);
        this.TryClose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not think about it that way yet, but now that you mention it making the dashboard the shell would probably solve most of the problems I'm having.

Comment: I'm sorry, but just now I noticed something wrong. I do not have a plain Show method on my windowmanager.

Comment: Updated.  With Silverlight you have a ShowDialog, ShowNotification, and ShowPopup.  ShowDialog displays a modal dialog for the specified view model, so you might want to switch the logic, and bootstrap your DashboardViewModel, and then if the user isn't authenticated, display the LoginViewModel using the WindowManager.ShowDialog method (so that it sits on top of your dashboard).  The user won't be able to get past this modal screen until they have successfully logged in, where you can just close the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I've just added a very simple login example SL4 project in my "lab repository" for Caliburn.Micro.

https://github.com/jenspettersson/Caliburn.Micro.Labs/tree/master/src/Login

It uses the Show class that Rob Eisenberg uses in his "Game Library" example to switch between views.

In the Login() method, it tells my Shell (your dashboard?) to show my LoginResultViewModel and sets the login result message.

```
yield return Show.Child<LoginResultViewModel>().In<IShell>().Configured(c => c.ResultMessage = "Successfully logged in!");
```

Check the code in my github repo.

I havent used Caliburn.Micro very much lately, so I am by no means an expert, but this way works for me.

//J

Edit: This answers how to navigate between views, if you want to show a "popup" to display if the login was successful, go with the other recomendations.

Comment: Thank you, this will definitely prove useful later on.